# Reducebykey returning null pointer exception in spark wordcount code

Tags: apache-spark

I am writing Word Count Code on Spark using Java.
There's no issue with code but when i run it, gives null pointer exception on reducebykey. Before that all steps provide return proper rdds.

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("app1").set("spark.rdd.compress","false").set("spark.shuffle.compress","false")
                .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> input_rdd = sc.textFile("C:/Users/skamal/Desktop/Spark_Input/file.txt", 1);


        RDDCreation obj=new RDDCreation();
        RedByKey obj1=new RedByKey();
        FlatMap obj2=new FlatMap();

        JavaRDD<String> word_rdd=input_rdd.flatMap(obj2);
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pair_RDD=word_rdd.mapToPair(obj);
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> red_RDD=pair_RDD.reduceByKey(obj1);

        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> a=pair_RDD.reduceByKey(
                  new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
                        public Integer call(Integer a, Integer b) { return a + b; }
                    });

        JavaRDD<String> key_list=pair_RDD.keys();
        JavaRDD<Integer> values_list=pair_RDD.values();


        System.out.println("The Data from Input RDD is..."+input_rdd.collect());
        System.out.println("************************");
        System.out.println("Pair RDD Data is.."+pair_RDD.collect());
    //  System.out.println("Keys From the RDD is.."+key_list.collect());
    //  System.out.println("Values From the RDD is.."+values_list.collect());
        System.out.println("The data from flat Map.."+word_rdd.collect());
        System.out.println("Reduce By Key RDD is.."+a.count());


    }
}
```

Comment: You have two `reduceByKey` calls, which is throwing?

Comment: The  line is commented in my code :  JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> red_RDD=pair_RDD.reduceByKey(obj1); still the same issue

Comment: I got the same code working on ubuntu machine (Stanalone) while on windows machine the error remains.. It seems to be an open bug